# Does gloox support BOSH and XMPP over BOSH?

Tags: xmpp, http-1.1

Does gloox library support BOSH(XEP 124) and XMPP over BOSH(XEP 206). Since gloox community is not active I thought this is right place to post this question.
Really appreciate any response on this.

Answer (score 0):

It does according to the documentation:
http://camaya.net/api/gloox-1.0-beta7/classgloox_1_1ConnectionBOSH.html